# VBA - Illegal Assignment in For Each

Tags: arrays, string, vba

```
Function FunctionName(str)

    Dim resultStr
    Dim wordArr
    wordArr = Array(Split(str, "_"))

    For Each item In wordArr
        resultStr = resultStr & UppercaseFirstLetter(item)
    Next item

    FunctionName = resultStr

End Function 'FunctionName
```

Consider the above for each loop in VBA. I keep getting the error of `Illegal Assignment 'item'`

Note: UppercaseFirstLetter is a function that converts the first letter of the given word into uppercase.

I'm new to VBA, any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: `item` is an object, and your function probably requires a `string`. Try what @GSerg suggested.

Comment: Can you further elaborate? I don't understand.

Comment: A function that converts the first letter of the given word into uppercase in VBA is `StrConv(text, vbProperCase)`. As for the error, it is not in the shown code, even though it unnecessarily wraps an array returned by `Split` into another array created by `Array`. Given this code, you should be getting error 13 Type mismatch.

Comment: Hints to become a better programmer in VBA:
Always use Option Explicit first in each file.
Always Dim with the variable type. In your case your Dims dimensions the variables to Variants so for readabillity you should type that: Dim resultStr As Variant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Debug.Print FunctionName("test1_test2")
End Sub 'Test
Function FunctionName(str)

    Dim resultStr As String
    Dim wordArr() As String
    Dim item As Variant
    wordArr = Split(str, "_")

    For Each item In wordArr
        resultStr = resultStr & UppercaseFirstLetter(item)
    Next item

    FunctionName = resultStr

End Function 'FunctionName
Function UppercaseFirstLetter(item As Variant)
    UppercaseFirstLetter = UCase(Mid(item, 1, 1)) & Mid(item, 2)
End Function 'UppercaseFirstLetter
```